# Counting number of affected rows when using mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a WinForms project in C# that connects to a MySQL database. I'm trying to count the number of rows in the result, i can't use `RecordsAffected` as this property only has the correct value after the read is complete and as you can see from the code below I need it before. Any idea's on how to do this?

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tigers WHERE Link='" + link + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr.RecordsAffected == 0)
    {
        //can't find in db               
    }
    else
    {
        //found at least 1 result
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `HasRows` instead :

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tigers WHERE Link='" + link + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(rdr.HasRows){
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
            //do stuff here
    }
} else {
    //nothing found
}
```

**Edit :** if you don't need to read the data you retrieve from the database and just want the count you could use :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tigers WHERE Link='" + link + "'";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i ended up using hasrow and it works brilliantly. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't *affect* much in the database when you perform a `SELECT` query. You are retrieving records that match your query. If you want to count the number of records that match your query you could use `count` along with a `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ExecuteScalar method like so:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

As an aside your current query may be vulnerable to a [Sql Injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You should consider parameterising your query, like so:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tigers WHERE Link=?link";

IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "?link";
param.Value = link;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using an `IDataReader` (which `MySqlDataReader` implements), there is no guarantee that the server knows how many rows are affected until the read completes.

I'd structure your code slightly differently:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tigers WHERE Link='" + link + "'";

using( MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn) )
{
    using( MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //found at least 1 result
        }

        if (rdr.RecordsAffected == 0)
        {
            //can't find in db
        }
    }
}
```